# Texbox to decimal with culture info

Tags: c#, decimal, cultureinfo

Im facing an issue with my texbox values to decimals. 
In belgium, the decimal character is ",". It works good on the UI, but once im passing these values to my method, its not reading the "," anymore.

Ive tried playing with culture info, but without luck.

Here it still gives me the correct values with the comma as a seperator. So for example here its still the correct value of "85,00"

```
   if (rdoNew.Checked)
        {
            productPresenter.addProduct(
                                    txtProductCode.Text, txtProductName.Text, txtProductDescription.Text,
                                    Convert.ToDecimal(txtPriceExVat.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToDecimal(txtPriceIncVat.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                                    txtProductSerial.Text, Convert.ToBoolean(checkboxIsService.Checked)
                                    );
        }
        else
        {
            productPresenter.updateProduct(Convert.ToInt32(cbProducts.SelectedValue), txtProductCode.Text, txtProductName.Text, txtProductDescription.Text,
                                    Convert.ToDecimal(txtPriceExVat.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToDecimal(txtPriceIncVat.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                    txtProductSerial.Text, Convert.ToBoolean(checkboxIsService.Checked));
        }
```

But The price priceExVat and priceIncVat in here, are for example now "8500"

```
 public void addProduct(string productCode, string productName, string productDescription, decimal priceExVat, decimal priceIncVat, string serialNumber, bool isService)
     {
         tbl_products product = new tbl_products();
         product.ProductCode = productCode;
         product.ProductName = productName;
         product.ProductDescription = productDescription;
         product.ProductPriceExVat = priceExVat;
         product.ProductPriceInclVat = priceIncVat;
         product.ProductSerialNumber = serialNumber;
         product.IsService = isService;
```

How I understood it, when i used the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, the string gets converted to the correct culture info. But i think im wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you *never* use your current culture or that specific culture (can be `fr-BE` or `nl-BE` since you didn't specify it) in your code.

Since `InvariantCulture` use `,` as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator), your code thinks this separator is a thousand separator not the decimal one.

That's why your your result will be `8500` not `85,00` (and I *assume* you wrote your `85000` as a typo)

If you use *that* specific culture in your code, I think it should be ok.

```
decimal.Parse("85,00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-BE"));
// 85,00
decimal.Parse("85,00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-BE"));
// 85,00
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had no idea that the invariantculture uses the "," as a numbergroup separator. Ive read it somewhere it could be used like this and it would get the information from the machine. But apperently not. Bad information then.